# How to find and decode efficiently Nth frame with libavcodec?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-processing, libavcodec

Please, this is not duplicate of similar posts!

I want to find and to decode Nth frame, for example 7th frame.

As I understood, using `time_base` I can calculate how many ticks is each frame and by multiplying it with 7 we will get position of 7th frame. To calculate the ticks I do

```
AVStream inStream = getStreamFromAVFormatContext();

int fps = inStream->r_frame_rate.num;
AVRational timeBase = inStream->time_base;

int ticks_per_frame = (1/fps) / timeBase;
int _7thFramePos = ticks_per_frame * 7;
```

1. Did I calculated correctly position of 7th frame? If I did, so to go to that frame I just do `av_seek_frame(pFormatCtx, -1, _7thFramePos, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY)`, right?
   What happens if the 7th frame was P-Frame or B-Frame, how I decode it?
2. I noticed that the calculated value differs from `inStream->codec->ticks_per_frame`, why? Shouldn't they be the same? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post explains the issue nicely.
http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/307-Picture-Go-Back.html

[1] comment for AVStream structure clearly mentions that "r_frame_rate" is a guess and may not be accurate, because even if I have frame-rate of (say) 25fps, in term of base_time I may have 24 or 26 frames in a second.

[2] To find the exact frame number you need to decode frame from the start and keep a counter, but that is very in-efficient, this can be optimized for some file-formats like MP4 where information about every frame is present in file-header.

Comment: can provide some example please?

Comment: so how I calculate the timestamp to pass to `av_seek_frame` function?

Comment: if you dont want to be 100% accurate you can also use avformat_seek_file() with AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME flag. If you want to be 100% accurate then you would start decode from the start of the stream and keep a counter till you reach the desired frame and stop decoding once you reach the desired frame number.

Comment: 1 - What `avformat_seek_file` with `AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME` will do? Which frame it will find, closest I-Frame to Nth or what? 2 - You mean if I need X times to get X frames, I'll start each time from the start of the stream?

Comment: 1. AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME - allows you to specify the seek position in terms for frame number, and avformat_seek_file() allows you to specify the min-max deviation from the desired frame number.                           2. yes if you need to goto frame X frame you need to decode first X frames, but this can be optimized if you can keep index of key frames for the first time and next time you can seek to closet key frame which is exact in avformat_seek_file() and then move to desired frame.

Comment: 1. I'm confused, if I can specify the frame number, so why it's not 100% accurate and cause deviation? 2. Assuming I know in advance the fps and it is **static**, is my calculation of frame above correct?